# How does npm know where to look for my index.js file?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

My pckage.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
...
```

How does it know where to find the `index.js` file? What if I have multiple index.js files in different directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: The `main` property is static, not relative.

The index.js is relative to the package root, or the `package.json`. If you have this.

```
.
├── package.json
├── index.js
└── utils.js
```

Then it will point to `./index.js`, as it is relative. If you have a `index.js` in `src/index.js`, the `main` will need to point to `src/index.js` instead.

Comment: By my `index.js` is in fact located in the `src` folder. Yet, the `package.json` file above works

Comment: Really? Try `cd`-ing to your directory and running `node .`. It will not work, because the `main` property is set incorrectly. If you run it with a direct path, such as `node src/index.js`, it will always work, since the `main` property is irrelevant.